# $.getJSON cant handle named function?

Tags: jquery, getjson

why jquery doesnt executed the function when i name the callback function?

```
$.getJSON("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showMyIP"),function (){
     console.log("test");}
```

dev tools shows that i get a correct json

```
showMyIP({"ip": "84.113.30.7"});
```

but he simple ignores the following function

if i replace showMyIP with ? and make it anonmyous it works.

also i have a another json which is 100% correct, where jquery refuses to run the anonymous function despite getting a correct json back wrapped in a anony. function, where in debugging i get a missing ; error on some Object which makes no sense at all to me, since there are no ; used in jsons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. First there's a random `)` in your code causing a syntax error.

Secondly, `$.getJSON` expects a JSON response, not JSONP. To do what you want use `$.ajax()` and set the correct `dataType`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: 'showMyIP',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the random ) was just a copy error. With ajax it works, but it still doesnt work my other json. He receives a correct jsonp, at least json lint says its ok. Any idea why it wouldnt work?

Comment: That could be due to a CORS problem. Hard to give you a definitive answer without seeing the code.

Comment: this is what the json looks like when i access it via the browser   [{"id":"vital_data","name":"Vital Data","timestamp":"2016-02-02_10:31","diastolic_pressure":"800","systolic_pressure":"120","heart_rate":"60","pressure_unit":"mm Hg","heart_rate_unit":"bpm"}]               and dev tools shows me a correct reponse.

Comment: Ok, but I need to see the *code* that gets the JSON, not the JSON itself. If you edit your question to include it I'll take a look

Comment: its the same code you gave me , i just swap the url.

Comment: *What* URL? You haven't given it anywhere...?

Comment: its a localhost java server, so i cant give you the url

Comment: Sorry, then there's not much I can help with then. If the above code doesn't work then it's most likely because either the endpoint doesn't return JSONP (I note that you seem confused about the difference between JSON and JSONP - they aren't interchangeable), or that you're blocked by a CORS issue. Given the output you gave above, that's JSON. Try using the above with `dataType: 'json'` and remove `jsonpCallback` completely

Comment: ok thx for the help, i tried json, with that i doesnt get anything back. . I noticed that content-type is application/json, but shouldnt it be javascript with the callback? maybe thats the problem

Comment: No, if it's JSON then `application/json` is correct. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, but with jsontest it returns application/javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1 where it works, and with localhost server its /json, so theres no problem with that?. Yesterday i used some code i found on stackoverlfow to try to debug it, and i remember getting a missing semilcon error in 1:5 on Obj 0, but the json is correct as you said.

Comment: i put an error function into the ajax call and it throws as exception:  object Object

Comment: but dev tools shows no error, and i see the correct json in the debugger